# Android edittext set Arbic and english text mix

Tags: android, programming-languages, android-edittext

i am going to set mix text on edittext like:`Xyz Pvt Ltd  فاتورة المبيعات         مبيعات التسليم          <0x09> Choclate Cake 10 x30.000 =  300.000`

Acualy i had set text like this but arbic text chage it Xyz Pvt Ltd  ف اتورة المبيعات         مبيعات التسليم           -Choclate Cake 10 x30.000 =  300.000

As you can see in first line after arbick text i had append <0X09> but it will append before arbick text that's proble

Comment: You will need to download the arabic font(.ttf) and use the same. I am not sure this is the best way.

Comment: once i download arbic text and set it then can it print arbic and english text both?

Comment: you will have to use two textviews i guess. i am not sure its the best way. So wait until someone posts a better idea.

Comment: @Raghunandan I had tried it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the unicode to arabic type with a convertor online and then setText the view with arabic font. For tamil I had used TAB font so I downloaded the tab font and had put it in my assets folder and then in setTypeFace I used the font. You can try the arabic encoded string and the font.

```
String EncodedString = "Üî¢î¤ò£òñ¢ : "; // Your arab encoded string
Typeface tfTab = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/tabkovai.ttf"); // Replace with arab font
tab.setTypeface(tfTab);
TextView.setText(EncodedString);
```